# Connecting fields in tables when the tables are already connected through other field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `osoby_dane` (
 `os_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `imie` text,
 `status` int(1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `osoby_rank` (
 `os_id` int(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 `os_rank` int DEFAULT 1000,
 `status` int(1),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rank` FOREIGN KEY (os_id) REFERENCES osoby_dane(os_id) on update cascade on delete restrict
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Example: 
osoby_dane:

```
os_id | imie | status |
1     |John  |1       |
```

osoby_rank:

```
os_id | os_rank | status |
 1    | 1400    | 1      |
```

My question is how can I (if i can at all..) connect fields in the same rows (status column) one to one (if i edit status field in one table then in second it will be changed automatically). And i don't want use trigger function

Comment: If it's redundant data, consider normalizing by deleting one of the statuses and simply join the records when reading them.

Comment: You can create a [FOREIGN KEY with ON UPDATE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: @MarcusAdams, a little-known fact is that InnoDB can do a foreign key reference to any indexed column, not just PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys. This is nonstandard, and can lead to some pretty weird effects, though.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I suppose you could use a foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` if the foreign key was on columns: `os_id`, `status`. This seems like a hack.

Comment: No FOREIGN KEY wont be work because every record in one table will be suit to records in second table

Comment: @MarcusAdams, for what it's worth, here's a SqlFiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/759e3/1

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks. You might have missed my last comment. I thought the OP wanted to update the status for the corresponding record (os_id = 1), not change them all where status = 1. Never mind, OP likes the hack.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, oh yeah, *smacks forehead* you're right. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make in osoby_rank  `CONSTRAINT fk_status FOREIGN KEY (os_id, status) REFERENCES osoby_dane(os_id, status) on update cascade` and in osoby_dane make `KEY status_idx(os_id, status)` it should be working

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use triggers or foreign keys, then there is no solution to automatically make `osoby_rank.status` update to match `osoby_dane.status`.

You'll have to change the `status` in both columns explicitly when you change one.

For example, you can do a multi-table update:

```
UPDATE osoby_dane INNER JOIN osoby_rank USING (os_id)
SET osoby_dane.status = 2,
    osoby_rank.status = 2
WHERE osoby_dane.os_id = 1;
```

Another solution, as @MarcusAdams suggested, is to store `status` in just one table or the other, to avoid the redundant column.